# Supporting retina background images iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create an image that fills the entire iPhone screen. For an iPhone 6, that means I should make an @2x image that's 750 x 1334 (since the screen size is 375 x 667). Should I also create an @3x image that's 1125 x 2001?

And then do I need to create a completely separate asset (i.e. different name, not just different @ suffix) for iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 Plus?

Comment: `@2x` and `@3x` have nothing to do with device size.

Answer (score 1):

All the recent phones from iPhone 5 have same aspect ratio of 16:9. As long as your image has the same aspect ratio, it will fill the screen properly. @2x only means that when you pass the name like image.png, it will search for image@2x.png on retina display devices, if it cannot find that, it will fall back to image.png. Same is with @3x which is for Plus models of iPhones. So answer to you question: Yes do create the 1125X2001 sized image with image@3x.png naming convention. That way you can avoid pixelization in Plus models.

Edit: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. Yes iPad Pro doesn't use 3x image.

Comment: The iPad Pro does not use `@3x` images, it uses `@2x` images.